# Add a legend to a figure

Tags: matplotlib, plot, legend, scatter-plot

Here is a code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
 
fig, subs = plt.subplots(4,3) #setting the shape of the figure in one line as opposed to creating 12 variables 
 
iris = load_iris() ##code as per the example 
data = np.array(iris['data'])
targets = np.array(iris['target'])
 
cd = {0:'r',1:'b',2:"g"}
cols = np.array([cd[target] for target in targets])

 
# Row 1 
 
subs[0][0].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[0][1].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,2], c=cols)
subs[0][2].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,3], c=cols)
 
# Row 2 
 
subs[1][0].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[1][1].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,2], c=cols)
subs[1][2].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,3], c=cols)
 
# Row 3 
 
subs[2][0].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[2][1].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[2][2].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,3], c=cols)
 
#Row 4 
 
subs[3][0].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[3][1].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[3][2].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,2], c=cols)
 
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

I would be interested in adding a legend indicating the red dots represent `'setosa'`, green dots `'versicolor'` and blue dots `'virginica'`. That legends would be at the bottom and center of the above picture. How can I do that?

I think I have to play with `fig.legend`, but I am not sure at all how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the targets in one of the subplots, and make the legend appear outside this plot. Here is what I obtained with your code:

[image: multiple scatter plots legend]

Here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

fig, subs = plt.subplots(4,3, constrained_layout=True) #setting the shape of the figure in one line as opposed to creating 12 variables

iris = load_iris() ##code as per the example
data = np.array(iris['data'])
target_names = iris['target_names']
targets = np.array(iris['target'])

cd = {0:'r',1:'b',2:"g"}
cols = np.array([cd[target] for target in targets])


# Row 1

subs[0][0].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[0][1].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,2], c=cols)
subs[0][2].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,3], c=cols)

# Row 2

subs[1][0].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[1][1].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,2], c=cols)
subs[1][2].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,3], c=cols)

# Row 3

subs[2][0].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[2][1].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[2][2].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,3], c=cols)

# Row 4
subs[3][0].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,0], c=cols)

# loop for central subplot at last row
for t, name in zip(np.unique(targets), target_names):
    subs[3][1].scatter(data[targets==t,3], data[targets==t,1], c=cd[t], label=name)
subs[3][1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(2, -.2), ncol=len(target_names))  # you can play with bbox_to_anchor for legend position

subs[3][2].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,2], c=cols)


plt.savefig('legend')
```

**EDIT**: I have also found this [post in the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html), where you can extract the scatter elements from the scatter plot directly (without using a `for` loop). I have tried on the IRIS dataset without being able to make it work.

Comment: You have made a vertical legend. Can you place that legend horizontally under the figure?

Comment: Yes, setting `bbox_to_anchor=(2, -.2)` and `ncol=len(target_names)` will do the trick (if you ask for 3 columns, the labels will expand horizontally). I will edit the answer.

Comment: Note that the axes need to shrink in order to prevent the legend to overlap too much with other axes. This can be probably tackled with adding a `constrained_layout=True` in the `plt.subplots` function.

Comment: This is perfect! :D

Answer (score 0):

Add `label='versicor'` etc to just one of your subplots:

```py
# Row 1 
 
subs[0][0].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=cols, label='virginica')
subs[0][1].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,2], c=cols, label='setosa')
subs[0][2].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,3], c=cols, label='versicolor')
```

Then you can call `fig.legend(loc='lower center', ncol=3)` before `plt.show()`.

I have set `ncol=3` to make it short and wide.

See my example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = range(1,11)
b = np.random.randn(10).cumsum()
c = np.random.randn(10).cumsum()
d = np.random.randn(10).cumsum()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(9,5))

ax1.plot(a,b, label = 'one')
ax1.plot(a,c, label = 'two')
ax1.plot(a,d, label = 'two')

ax2.plot(a,c)

fig.legend(loc='lower center', ncol=3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That did not answer my question. Can you make it work with the example I provided to you?

Comment: I showed you what to add in your code, and gave an example, not sure how that didn't answer the Q. Have you added the `label={species}` as I showed? (I don't have your dataset).

Comment: Yes, you have the dataset. You just have to use the line `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris` to import it. For the moment, that answer it is not fine. I can't work with that

Comment: I don't have sklearn installed, nor do I want to install it.